# Make 3 columns per row in twig symfony while looping twig

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig

Please help . I want to appear list of images 3 images per row while loop using twig. How do I that?

here's my code

```
{% for siteAdministrator in siteAdministrators[5:] %}
   {% if loop.index0 is divisibleby(3) %}
       <section class="row team-members-row">
          <div> array </div>
       </section>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE:**
The current result of my code is.. 1 image per row something like this.

```
// 1st loop
<section class="row team-members-row">
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
            // image 1
    </div>  
</section>
// 2nd loop
<section class="row team-members-row">
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
            // image 2
    </div>  
</section>
// 3rd loop
<section class="row team-members-row">
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
            // image 3
    </div>  
</section>
and so on.. 1 image per row
```

I want to appear images something like this.

```
 // 1st loop
<section class="row team-members-row">
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
            // image 1
    </div>
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
           // image 2
    </div>
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
           // image 3
    </div>    
</section>
// 2nd loop
<section class="row team-members-row">
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
            // image 4
    </div>
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
           // image 5
    </div>
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
           // image 6
    </div>    
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should embrace in the if statement only the display of the section tag as follow:

```
{% for siteAdministrator in siteAdministrators[5:] %}
   {% if loop.index0 is divisibleby(3) %}
    <section class="row team-members-row">
{% endif %}
          <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
          {{siteAdministrator.name}} 
          </div>
   {% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) or loop.last %}
    </section>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Check the last element for closing the tag.

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/me9kbh) a working example. And this is the output:

```
<section class="row team-members-row">
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
    image6 
    </div>
        <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
    image7 
    </div>
        <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
    image8 
    </div>
</section>
    <section class="row team-members-row">
    <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
    image9 
    </div>
        <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
    image10 
    </div>
        <div class="other-team-members positionrelative floatleft withdropdown">
    image11 
    </div>
</section>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi thank you, please read my update above, your doesn't show as my sample above

Comment: hi @jlacsonph I update my answer, can you explain better if this don't fill your need?

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<section class="row team-members-row">
   {% for siteAdministrator in siteAdministrators[5:] %}
     {% if loop.index0 is divisibleby(3) %}
          <div> array </div>
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
</section>
```

Comment: Hi thank you, please read my update above, your doesn't show as my sample above.